# PCSC with windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, nfc, pcsc

I have an SCL3711 smart card reader connected to my PC. Is there any way in which I can get my windows 8 phone to recognize my PC as an NFC device and transfer data via NFC between them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SCL3711 and Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107656/scl3711-and-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the peer to peer communication.
I don't know if there are any software but you can develop it yourself (more easier way is to use c#).